# How can I implement Paypal Native Checkout SDK in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, paypal

I have searched for the [Native Checkout SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/) example for android, But didn't find any example or documentation about it. The paypal documentation code is showing error when I tried to implement it. And is there any java version of integration available?

Comment: "is showing error when I tried to implement it" .... yes?

Comment: The samples are in Kotlin, which interoperates fully with Java.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/native-checkout/android/

Perfect documentation for you; but you must do the following things first to work properly.

1. Select your app from the My Apps & Credentials page on the Developer Dashboard and:

**** Enter a Return URL. You can use an Android App Link registered within the Developer Console to handle SDK redirects. Alternatively, you can use your Application ID (typically referenced via BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID) and register your Application ID with ://paypalpay as the suffix. For example, if your Application ID is com.paypal.app, input com.paypal.app://paypalpay in the Developer Console

**** Select the Native Checkout SDK checkbox, found within the Advanced options of the Accept payments option.

*** Select the Connect with PayPal (formerly Log In with PayPal) checkbox and the Full name and Email checkboxes found within the Advanced options.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I was able to implement it earlier.